# Как выделить текущий аргумент болдом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пишу подсказки(snippets) для текстового редактора. При вызове функции у меня показывается структура функции со всеми обязательными и необязательными аргументами. Как мне выделять текущий аргумент **жирным** текстом? Например:

sum( number1; **number2**)

Сейчас я использую функцию `replace`, но вставленный тэг остаётся текстом, как это можно поправить?

```
function boldString(str, substr) {
  return str.replace(substr, '<b>'+substr+'</b>');
}
// result
sum( number1; <b>number2</b>)
```

Как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как это выводится? укажите HTML

Comment: с помощью jquery: 

res = boldString(hint, substr)

$('.hint').text( res )

Comment: Я про html по типу в DIV текст вставляете?

Comment: Сделайте демку через сниппет

Comment: Один из примеров реализации есть на английском [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819435/js-replace-place-b-tag-in-string-where-string)

Comment: я импользую тег <p>

Comment: Так [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FVz2D/) не подходит?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r03q5atf/ - посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Подсказка динамическая или статическая должна быть? если сейчас удалить строку полностью то вообще <b> не правильно ставится, как это должно работать? Что должно быть если первого числа нет, что должно быть если вместо `sum(number;number)` человек нечаянно укажет `sum(number:number)`. Я так понимаю подсвечиваться должна та часть, которую пользователь в данный момент заполняет?

Comment: Сейчас я делаю механизм отображения текущего аргумента, остальное пока не важно. Подсказка динамическая, нужно просто отобразить текущий аргумент жирным текстом.

Comment: Проблема в том, что тег вставляется в виде текста.

Comment: Замените строку `$('.hint').text( res )` на `$('.hint').html( res )` [Подробней](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо большое! Как здесь лайк ставить? :DDD

Comment: Стрелочка вверх возле сообщения))

Comment: Вижу только флажок

Comment: Видимо нет каких-то прав, в любом случае, Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо!